# AVD + Eclipse : always runs the same project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have a problem when launching a project from Eclipse in my Android Virtual Device.

I have multiple projects in Eclipse and when I run one of them by pressing right click on a project -> Run As -> Android Application it always run the samen project. (The first project I made in Eclipse)

Does somebody knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click in the folder on the project that you want to run, then click run.

Answer (score 1):

Check If you have changed your manifest.xml accordingly. It once happened with me because i copied code from one manifest to the other. 
set the path properly for the default activity